# Automatically change urls in browser

Tags: browser, plugins, script

We have a monitor at the office that runs a couple of of full screen applications that keep track of different parts of our production environment.

I'd now like to have a way to flip between 3-4 url:s in a scheduled manner. So the view on the monitor rotates and we can see possible errors in the different views of a couple of different web applications.

Do you know of a script, plug in or application that does this?

**Update** Looks like [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/2668) can do what I need for FF. My dream scenario would of course be to have a similar thing working in Chrome and not necessarily by setting up tabs.

Comment: this feature has been requested in the chrome wishlist, you may add your vote: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=534c294641b65dad&hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can code an HTML-Page "loader" with a large IFRAME. On the loader page there runs a javascript wich continously loads the different URLs into the IFRAME.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind editing a little html yourself try this.

http://javascript.internet.com/navigation/web-slideshow.html